# Como adicionar elemento dentro de um arrayList que se encontra dentro de outro ArrayList que por sua vez se encontra dentro de um HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

A dúvida é a seguinte: tenho as Classes Aluno, Disciplina, Nota, Turma.

Preciso adicionar um valor double em um ArrayList que está em um objeto da classe Disciplina, mas a classe Disciplina se encontra dentro em um ArrayList e este ArrayList está dentro de um HashMap:

esse é o método que estou tentando adicionar a nota:

```
public void addNota(String numeroMatricula, String disciplina,double nota){
    Iterator i = formaTurma.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Aluno aluno = (Aluno)i.next();
        if(aluno.getNumeroMatricula().equals(numeroMatricula)){
            ArrayList<Disciplina> disc = new ArrayList<Disciplina>();
            disc.addAll(formaTurma.get(aluno));
            for(int j = 0; j < disc.size(); j++){
                if(disc.get(j).getNome().equals(disciplina)){
                    O QUE FAÇO AQUI??
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como manipulo esse método? Só falta eu adicionar a nota dentro do arrayList, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Answer (score 2):

- Você não disse o que exatamente é o campo `formaTurma`. Suponho que seja um `Map<Aluno, List<Disciplina>>`, correto? Idealmente eu não deveria ter que supor isso, uma vez que você deveria ter informado na sua pergunta.
- Idealmente deveria existir um `Map<String, Aluno>` em algum lugar para que você não seja obrigado a percorrer o `formaTurma` procurando o `Aluno` que importa, pois a ideia do `Map` é exatamente te dar o valor quando você dá a chave. Se você desconhece a chave e é obrigado a procurá-la dentro do `keySet()` do `Map`, então você está fazendo algo errado.
- Idealmente, as disciplinas de um aluno deveriam estar dentro da própria classe `Aluno`, e não em um `Map` externo. Assim eu poderia utilizar `aluno.getDisciplinas()` para achar as disciplinas de um aluno ao invés de usar `formaTurma.get(aluno)`. Provavelmente isso demonstra algum sério problema na orientação a objetos. Além disso, estas disciplinas por aluno idealmente deveriam ser um `Map<String, Disciplina>` para que eu não precisasse procurar a disciplina correta dentro de uma lista.
- Porque ao invés de iterar a lista de disciplinas do `Aluno`, você está criando uma nova lista e iterando esta nova lista? Não seria bem mais fácil e mais simples iterar a lista original?
- Porque você itera a lista de disciplinas usando o `get(int)` ao invés de usar o *enhanced-for* ou o `Iterator` que seria a forma mais simples e natural de iterá-las?
- Você disse que a lista de notas está dentro da classe `Disciplina`, mas não demonstrou como faço para obtê-la, e com isso não dá para responder a sua pergunta sem ter que fazer algum tipo de suposição que eu não deveria estar fazendo. Vou supor que há na classe `Disciplina` um método `getNotas()` que retorna um `List<Double>`, mas se eu estiver errado, é porque você não deu informações suficientes para que a sua pergunta pudesse ser respondida.

Enfim, se tudo isso fosse observado, eu só precisaria fazer isso:

```java
private Map<String, Aluno> alunos;

public void addNota(String numeroMatricula, String disciplina, double nota) {
    Aluno aluno = alunos.get(numeroMatricula);
    if (aluno == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("O aluno com número de matrícula " + numeroMatricula + " não existe.");
    Disciplina d = aluno.getDisciplinas().get(disciplina);
    if (disciplina == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("O aluno com número de matrícula " + numeroMatricula + " não possui nenhuma disciplina " + disciplina + ".");
    d.getNotas().add(nota);
}
```

Ou se você tiver como garantir que os parâmetros `numeroMatricula` e `disciplina` sempre serão válidos, você pode simplificar ainda mais:

```java
private Map<String, Aluno> alunos;

public void addNota(String numeroMatricula, String disciplina, double nota) {
    alunos.get(numeroMatricula).getDisciplinas().get(disciplina).getNotas().add(nota);
}
```

Entretanto se você não puder mudar a estrutura da classe `Aluno` e nem puder mudar o formato do `Map` `formaTurma` para `Map<Aluno, Map<String, Disciplina>>` ou para `Map<String, Map<String, Disciplina>>` e nem poder adicionar um `Map<String, Aluno>` em algum lugar, então eu faria o seguinte:

```java
private Map<Aluno, List<Disciplina>> formaTurma;

private Aluno procurarAlunoPorNumeroDeMatricula(String numeroMatricula) {
    for (Aluno aluno : formaTurma.keySet()) {
        if (aluno.getNumeroMatricula().equals(numeroMatricula)) return aluno;
    }
    return null;
}

public void addNota(String numeroMatricula, String disciplina, double nota) {
    Aluno aluno = procurarAlunoPorNumeroDeMatricula(numeroMatricula);
    if (aluno == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("O aluno com número de matrícula " + numeroMatricula + " não existe.");
    List<Disciplina> disciplinas = formaTurma.get(aluno);
    for (Disciplina d : disciplinas) {
        if (d.getNome().equals(disciplina)) {
            d.getNotas().add(nota);
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("O aluno com número de matrícula " + numeroMatricula + " não possui nenhuma disciplina " + disciplina + ".");
}
```

Ou se você estiver usando java 8:

```java
private Map<Aluno, List<Disciplina>> formaTurma;

public void addNota(String numeroMatricula, String disciplina, double nota) {
    formaTurma.entrySet().stream() // Itera todos os Map.Entry<Aluno, List<Disciplina>>.
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().getNumeroMatricula().equals(numeroMatricula)) // E escolhe só os que tiverem o número de matrícula correto (mesmo que seja só uma).
            .findFirst() // Obtém um Optional<Map.Entry<Aluno, List<Disciplina>>> que contém o primeiro (e supostamente único) entry, se ele de fato existir. 
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("O aluno com número de matrícula " + numeroMatricula + " não existe.")) // Se o entry não existir lança exceção.
            .getValue().stream() // E itera o List<Disciplina>.
            .filter(d -> d.getNome().equals(disciplina)) // E escolhe só as que tiverem o nome correto (mesmo que seja só uma).
            .findFirst() // Obtém um Optional<Disciplina> que contém a primeira (e supostamente única) disciplina, se ela de fato existir.
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("O aluno com número de matrícula " + numeroMatricula + " não possui nenhuma disciplina " + disciplina + ".")) // Se a disciplina não existir lança exceção.
            .getNotas() // Obtém o List<Double>.
            .add(nota); // E adiciona a nota lá.
}
```